# Reading and editing a text file from windows cmd prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

Don't ask me why but i want to hit a certain url when my public ip address changes(I don't have and can't get a fixed ip) so i have created a batch file which opens the url(I have managed to save my public ip address in a variable and it pastes in the url) and made a scheduled task so that batch file runs after a certain time interval. But it is not efficient, I want to open the url whenever my ip address changes so i wanted to make a text file in which the batch file keeps writing my ip address and whenever it changes the url gets open automatically. Is it even possible??
**here is the code i am using to put my ip address in the url**::

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%A in (
  'nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2^>NUL^|find "Address:"'
) Do set ExtIP=%%B
Echo External IP is : %ExtIP%
start http://%ExtIP%             #this is where I put the url
```

Comment: Currently it seems you just want someone to improve your code or method. This is not an 'ask for advice on how to go about your project or task' type of site. This site helps you to fix a specific, single, and reproducible issue with your provided code. "It's not efficient" is not a issue, unless you provide your explanation of which specific part of your written code is working inefficiently, something to compare that inefficiency with, _(without seeing something work more efficiently, we have no foundation for the efficiency level)_, and what you've done yourself in trying to fix that issue.

Comment: I am using a service which requires my ip address , but since it changes every now and then i have to change the ip address Manually on there site. They have provided a api link in which i can paste my userid login and ip address. I just want to automate this process.

Comment: I do not wish to have a conversation with you! What you need to do is address the concerns I raised in my comment, by creating an on topic, understandable and answerable question, complete with your code, and all supporting information required for us to reproduce it, and assist you further. Please take the [tour], then read through [ask], and each of its linked pages, to help you to edit this question accordingly.

Comment: sure i am creating a new topic ill put my code there. Sorry if i was rude

Comment: Please do not create a new topic! use the **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65793585/edit)** button, and fix this one.

Comment: Ok done! hope there is no issue this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to save the variable to a file and read it again:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions Disabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%~dp0"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%A in (
  'nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2^>NUL^|find "Address:"'
) Do set ExtIP=%%B

<save.ip set /p SavIP=
if "%SavIP%" neq "%ExtIP%" (
  echo %date% %time~0,5% : IP changed from %SavIP% to %ExtIP%.
  >save.ip echo %ExtIP%
  start http://%ExtIP%             #this is where I put the url
) else (
  echo ExtIP didn't change. Nothing to do.
)
```